# Get server time and date as string and pass it to txt file

Tags: php, regex, forms, datetime

I'm trying to get server date and time and send it to email or write to txt file from simple php form.

here is a sample of code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb');

$datum=date("y-m-d");

$upisufajl =  ("\"{$_POST['firstName']}\",\"{$_POST['lastName']}\",\"{$_POST['email']}\",\"{$_POST['company']}\",\"{$_POST['datum']}\",\"{$_POST['oblik']}\",\"{$_POST['kategorija']}\",\"{$_POST['podkategorija']}\",\"{$_POST['message']}\"\n");
```

when do I need to write insted of `{$_POST['datum']}` to write date in txt file. everything elese works fine, but it doesnt show date.

echo `date("r");` shows date and time correctly. do I need to convert it to string to be able to write it in txt file?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `$_POST['datum']` doesn't exist (at least that we can see in this code). It's just `$datum`.

```
$upisufajl = ("\"{$_POST['firstName']}\",\"{$_POST['lastName']}\",\"{$_POST['email']}\",\"{$_POST['company']}\",\"{$datum}\",\"{$_POST['oblik']}\",\"{$_POST['kategorija']}\",\"{$_POST['podkategorija']}\",\"{$_POST['message']}\"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$datum` has not been added to your variable `$upisufajl`. I assume `$upisufajl` is what you are writing to a text file.